# Do these sentences make sense? How to use "a ray of sunshine" and "a breath of fresh air"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> Her ray of sunshine is to reach the peak of Mount Everest.

> It was a breath of fresh air after Manila Bay was cleaned by different organizations.

These two sentences are quoted from this English lesson material. (https://eikaiwa.weblio.jp/information/per-level-material/per-level-expert/environmental-conservation)

The Cambridge Dictionary says that "a ray of sunshine" is "*a happy person who makes others feel happy, especially in a difficult situation*" and that "a breath of fresh air" is "*someone or something that is new and different and makes everything seem more exciting*".

I don't think the two sentences above do not seem to make sense to me.  Are they really correct?

Comment: This [& your last question] is why English lessons should be written by someone native.

Answer (score 2):

*Her ray of sunshine is to reach the peak of Mount Everest,* is a very uncommon usage of *ray of sunshine*.  I would say that it is an incorrect usage.

A *ray of sunshine* is something or someone that metaphorically provides hope, encouragement, or relief in a place of darkness and woe.

> Tina was a ray of sunshine while we were imprisoned, bringing us good food and medicine to keep us healthy.

A *breath of fresh air* is something that brings relief to a situation or person. It implies there has a been a change for the better.

> After listening to my six year old practice the clarinet all day, Uncle Bob's off-key singing is a breath of fresh air.

Your first example sentence does not demonstrate that any relief or encouragement was provided.  If you want to call something a ray of sunshine, you should show how it shines light on a dark situation. It would be better expressed.

> After the avalanches, her reaching the peak of Everest was a ray of sunshine.

Your second example sentence does not imply a breath of fresh of air.  You have not provided something in contrast to the breath of fresh air. You need to tell me *what* has changed for the better. Your sentence would be better expressed --

> After so many cleaning companies tried and failed to clean Manila Bay, Old Bay Cleaners proved to be a breath of fresh air.

The above example is probably not the best.  I would hesitate to call the services provided by an environmental clean-up company a breath of fresh air but the structure of the sentence demonstrates my point.